# Update data array in the same row

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I would like to approve leave application based on dates for example as below :

[image]

```
echo "<select name='app_status[]' required>
<option value='' selected>Pending</option>
<option value='1'>Approve</option>
<option value='2'>Reject</option></select>";

$app_status = array();
if(is_array($app_status)) {
  foreach($_POST['app_status'] as $key1=>$value1) { 
     $app_status[]=$value1;
  }         
}

for($loop = 0; $loop < count($app_status); $loop++) {
  if($app_status[$loop]=="" || $app_status[$loop]==null)
  $error=1;
}

if(isset($error))
$error=1;
else
$error=0;

if($error==0) {     
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($app_status); $i++) {
     $str = $app_status[$i];
     $sql= "UPDATE leaves_apply SET app_status ='$str' WHERE app_id='$app_id'";
     $query2 = mysqli_query($sql);
  }
}
```

[image]

For example if I approve the leaves for 12/8/2017 - 15/8/2017 except for 16/8/2017, I will get an output like this **11112** And when I check the database, the column app_status will only update 2, as if it only read the last data and not the first four data. If possible I would like the data **11112** to be update in the **app_status column** for **app_id no 1357**. I'm not sure if this is the right way, please help me as I'm new to this. Thank you.

Comment: I see no WHERE clause in your SQL statement. Without this all records would be updated to the last value processed.

Comment: @dougtesing.net yes sorry I missed it, but after adding the WHERE clause I still got the same output.

Comment: Are you able to give some details about the database structure such as table columns? What column uniquely identifies each leave record? Is it app_id or is that the same for more than one record? Also where does $app_id come from - I don't see it being set anywhere in your code listing.

Comment: @dougtesting.net I've updated the above questions together with the database, hope it will make you understand better. Also I didn't include $app_id in the above code, but I've tried and checked it updates the right app_id. The only concern now is that it only updates 2 in the app_status column instead of 11112 just like how i want it to be.

Comment: I think I understand now. Thank you. Give me a few minutes to write some code and i'll get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this modification should do what you would like...

```
if($error==0) {     

  // Declare the string for the app_status
  $str = "";

  // Loop though the statuses and put together the statuses
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($app_status); $i++) {
     $str .= $app_status[$i];
  }

  // Update the database record
  $sql= "UPDATE leaves_apply SET app_status = '$str' WHERE app_id='$app_id'";
  $query2 = mysqli_query($sql);
}
```

Please remember to escape your database queries to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: If the app_status column is an int you might want to have a value for pending otherwise the 1112 etc won't match up to the days. Personally I would do this entirely differently, possibly having a leave_date table joining to this one with an entry for each date and a status column with a single value for each day.

Comment: Yes i agree with you would have done a different way too, but this is last minute changes and if I were to change, probably takes time. So this is for the time being. Anyway, try out your code and it works. Could you explain further the changes you've made. I would like to understand better

Comment: Great, yeah no worries. Because there is only 1 row in the database table for this leave application we only need to update the database once, so I moved the SQL after the loop. The other change was appending the app_status to the $str as a string with .= each loop this adds the status for the day. So "1" for the first day, then it appends another "1" for the second day making the $str = "11"  and so on giving us "11112" in $str before the SQL query then updates the database. Then because 11112 is a valid number it will save in the app_status column in the database which looks to be an int.